# Create a definition to substitute words in a sentence in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know how to substitute individual letters in a normal for loop without using the replace function but I don't know how to do it on a definition with 3 parameters. Per example

```
def substitute(sentence, target, replacement)
```

Basically it'll be like `substitute("The beach is beautiful", "beach", "sky")`and give back The sky is beautiful. How do you do that without using the replace or find function?
Thanks

```
def replace_word(sentence, target, replacement):
newSentence = ""
for target in sentence:
    if target in sentence:
        newSentence += replacement
        print(newSentence)
    else:
        True
    return newSentence
```

Comment: What have _you_ tried to solve this?

Comment: Ive tried doing for target in sentence and then if target inn sentence then target = replacement and give back the word but it doesnt do anything

Comment: @Jonathan You should provide the sample code of what you tried, so that we may help you resolve any issues you code or algorithm may have.

Comment: There I edited it @ilim

Comment: There are a few indentation problems there @Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way.

```
def replace_word(sentence, target, replacement):
    newSentenceLst = []
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word == target:
            newSentenceLst.append(replacement)
        else:
            newSentenceLst.append(word)
    return ' '.join(newSentenceLst)

res = replace_word("The beach is beautiful", "beach", "sky")

# 'The sky is beautiful'
```

**Explanation**

- Indentation is *crucial* in Python. Learn how to use it correctly.
- Use `str.split` to split your sentence into words.
- Initialise a list and add words to the list via `list.append`.
- If the word equals your target, then use replacement instead, via `if` / `else`.
- Finally use `str.join` to join your words with whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
def replace_word(sentence, target, replacement):
    newSentence = ""
    for word in sentence.split(" "):
        if word == target:
            newSentence += replacement
        else:
            newSentence += word
        newSentence += " "
    return newSentence.rstrip(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def substitue(sentence,target,replacement):
  x=re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  sentence).split()
  x = [word.replace(target,replacement) for word in x]
  sent=" ".join(x)
  return sent
```

try this

Comment: This uses the replace function when the OP wants a solution without it.

Comment: He said he knows how to replace using for loop,but he did not know how to create substitute function.At no point he said he did not want to use replace function

Comment: " How do you do that without using the replace or find function?"

Comment: The OP's question says: "How do you do that without using the replace or find function?"

Comment: oh srry didnt read that but your output does not add space after each word plz correct it.